# Is it possible to conditionally hide and show MUI Tabs Header?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Please advise on how to hide or show MUI Tabs header conditionally?

I am trying to hide my MUI Tabs header conditionally on hover on a specific area or on click of another button, is it doable? Experts, please advise a feasible approach if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Added a state to toggle display of a tab. Modified the Basic Tabs demo code from https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  value: number;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function BasicTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  // State to toggle tab 3
  const [showItemThree, setShowItemThree] = React.useState(true);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      
      {/* Button to toggle tab 3 */}
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setShowItemThree(!showItemThree)}>
        Toggle ITEM THREE display
      </Button>

      {/* Tabs */}
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          
          {/* Conditionally show/hide tab 3 */}
          {showItemThree && 
            <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
          }
        
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```